# Magenerds Baseprice not working in Magento 2.4.6?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, price

I am using Magenerds Baseprice in my shop. It worked in version 2.3, in 2.4.6 it stopped working - the base price is not updated on swatch change. I tracked it down to `\vendor\magenerds\baseprice\view\frontend\templates\configurable\afterprice.phtml`.

The `options` var is undefined: `var options = _.object(_.keys(swatchWidget.optionsMap), {});`

And I guess thats the reason why `result` is also undefined: `result = swatchWidget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[_.findKey(swatchWidget.options.jsonConfig.index, options)];`

Maybe in 2.4.6 the structure changed and so the options can not be read like in 2.3. Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks!